# How to get the short date format string from the current locale in C/C++?

Tags: c, windows, date

The following code (Windows, C++) sets the current locale and retrieves a formatted short date string, formatted according to locale's short date format "%c".

```
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

  strftime (buffer,80,"%c",timeinfo);
```

Say this gives "31/01/2012" for a given date and locale.
This corresponds to a date format of "%d/%m/%Y", although "%c" has been specified.

Is there a way i can get the format string itself, i.e. "%d/%m/%Y" for a given locale?

Comment: Nitpick: "31/01/2012" cannot correspond to a date format of "%m/%d/%Y" but it can correspond to a date format of "%d/%m/%Y".

Comment: @Ian Abbott: Sure. edited.

Answer (score 2):

There is a call in langinfo to do this

as a simple demo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <langinfo.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", nl_langinfo( D_FMT ) );
}
```

If your C compiler is not POSIX compliant, and I thought Windows was supposed to be, then perhaps the answers at this question would be more of a guide

[What is the correct way to get a LOCALE_SSHORTDATE that is guaranteed to have a full (4-digit) year number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632211/what-is-the-correct-way-to-get-a-locale-sshortdate-that-is-guaranteed-to-have-a)

Comment: That is an external library. No standard C or C++ solution? Or a WinApi call?

Comment: POSIX is pretty standard.  I thought Windows was supposed to be POSIX complient.  See link added to answer for native windows question along your your area of interest